# Output time period of each pulse signals to determine the duty cycle

Tags: duty-cycle

[image]

Dear all,

I build on an oscillator and want to detect its duty cycle in order to compenstate the oscillator which is used to sensing the environment change.
After I get the V(vtime_all) which shows that the time period between 1st pulse to 2nd pulse is the pulse width (pulse active time) and 1st to 3rd is the total period of the signal (3rd to 4th is PW, 3rd to 5th is total T), I would like to generate a voltage to represent the current duty cycle ratio, but I have no idea to make the next block.

May be using counter, integrator or something else. Thank you for your time reading my problems.

After using counter, I get the output like figure 2 below. In order to detect the duty-cycle, the next step I would like to build a divider which shows 1 at PW region and 0 at the other region. If you have others way, I'm appreicate your suggesetions and willing to learn more. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: the next step depends on what electrical quantity you are trying to generate

Comment: Dear jsotola, I would like to generate voltage signal which represent the time period of PW and total period.  I have no idea which operator or circuit schematic will be proper to use in this situation. Thanks for you kind reply.

Comment: PW = pulse width?